# How can I change the visualization of a ListPointPlot3D?

Tags: plotting, graphics, probability-or-statistics, display

I have the following code

```
plot1 = ListPointPlot3D[{Table[{10, x, 
     PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD]1, x]}, {x, 18000, 34000, 2}], 
   Table[{20, x, PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD]2, x]}, {x, 18000, 34000, 2}], 
   Table[{30, x, PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD]3, x]}, {x, 18000, 34000, 2}]}, 
  PlotRange -> All, Filling -> Bottom, ImageSize -> 600, 
  AxesLabel -> {"Time", "Is" }, AxesStyle -> Directive[Bold, 18], 
  TicksStyle -> 
   Directive[
    FontSize -> 
     12]];
plot2 = Graphics3D[{Thick, Line[{{10, 0.0001, 0}, {30, 0.0001, 0}}]}];
Show[plot1, plot2]
```

Which produces this figure

[image]

I want to change the X axis so that it goes between 18000 and 34000. As you can see in the code, I have tried to write it as `{x, 18000, 34000, 2}` of all three pdfs, but, as you can see in the figure, it doesn't seem to work. Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: can't run your code. It missing some definitions.

Comment: Specify a plot range in the "Show" command: `Show[plot1, plot2, 
 PlotRange -> {{10, 30}, {18000, 34000}, {0, 0.0004}}]`

Comment: @Nasser I am sorry, but to arrive to said figure, it is necessary to load data from external txt files, so even if I published my whole code, you wouldn't be able to run it.

Comment: @DanielHuber I have tried your solution and I am afraid it doesn't work, the displayed figure is empty

Comment: OK, I understand. But it will make it easier for someone to help if they can run the code and try things. Otherwise it will just giving somethings to try and fail process which is not efficient. Try `Show[plot1,plot2,Options[plot2]]` and see if this helps

Comment: @Nasser Another thing that I have written that works is `pickernel1 = 
 Plot[{PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD]1, x], PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD]2, x], 
   PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD]3, x]}, {x, 18000, 34000}, Filling -> Axis, 
  PlotLegends -> 
   Placed[{Style["t = 1364.30 s", 18], Style["t = 1403.28 s", 18], 
     Style["t = 1442.26 s", 18]}, {0.75, 0.75}], AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
  PlotRange -> All, FrameLabel -> {"PDF of haversine distance AB" }, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Bold, 18], 
  TicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 12], Frame -> True, 
  ImageSize -> 600]`

Comment: ``plot2` causes the problem.  Just omit it to get what you want.  However, if you choose not to, use `Show[plot1, plot2, PlotRange -> {All, {18000, 34000}, All}]`.  I have demonstrated it using a made-up distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with PlotRange specified in Show:

```
\[ScriptCapitalD]1 = NormalDistribution[28000, 2000];
\[ScriptCapitalD]2 = NormalDistribution[25000, 2000];
\[ScriptCapitalD]3 = NormalDistribution[24000, 4000];
plot1 = ListPointPlot3D[{Table[{10, x, 
      PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD]1, x]}, {x, 18000, 34000, 2}], 
    Table[{20, x, PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD]2, x]}, {x, 18000, 34000, 2}], 
    Table[{30, x, PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD]3, x]}, {x, 18000, 34000, 2}]},
    PlotRange -> All, Filling -> Bottom, ImageSize -> 600, 
   AxesLabel -> {"Time", "Is"}, AxesStyle -> Directive[Bold, 18], 
   TicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 12]];
plot2 = Graphics3D[{Thick, Line[{{10, 0.0001, 0}, {30, 0.0001, 0}}]}];
Show[plot1, plot2, 
 PlotRange -> {{10, 30}, {18000, 34000}, {0, 0.0004}}]
```

[image]